# how to get different style for different classes of one parent class in one loop I tried doing this... using jquery ,

Tags: jquery, css

how to get different style for different classes of one parent class  in one loop I tried doing this... using jquery ,
 in this code the output is not as I was expecting it to be , instead all the class got the same style but I wanted the margin-top to be different .

```
  function addUsers(){
    for (let index = 0; index <sp.length; index++) {
      $(".peopless").addClass(` ppl${index+1}`);
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    addUsers();
    var op = sp.length;
    for(let i=0;i<op;i++)
    {
      console.log(`.ppl${i+1}`)
      $(`.ppl${i+1}`).css({
          'display': 'inline',
          'width':'280px',
          'height': '70px',
          'border':'2px solid white',
          'position': 'absolute',
          'margin-top':'30px',
          'top':`${10+i+1}%`,
          'left':'20px'
      });
      $(`.ppl${i+1}`).append(sp[i]);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why do you need jQuery?

Comment: because i will be getting some data from the database and according to the length of the number of users I will be created different div's and I want to assign different styles for those div's and for that I need jquery to assign different styles and margin's to the div's

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do anything. You have a legacy requirement with jQuery or you don't have, that's it. I would suggest to stop using deprecated libraries

Comment: then what should I do to dynamically change the styling of the div's

Comment: If on a list, you can use `querySelectorAll` to query for element such as `document.querySelectorAll('.my-class').forEach((i) => i.classList.add('new-class'))` and if you look for a unique element then `document.querySelector('.my-class').classList.add('new-class')` . `querySelector` work from any node so you can have benefit of context. `classList.add` is a method of classList for all node, but there is also `classList.remove`, `classList.toggle`. No reason to use jQuery

Comment: Replace `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` with `window.onload = function onload() { .. }`

Comment: `$(".peopless")` = `document.querySelector('.peopless')`, and `$(".peopless").addClass` = `document.querySelector('.peopless').addClass`, etc...